# Quick question: do I need a resistor for a keyboard key switch

Tags: current, resistors

I am building 3D printed keyboard. I am probably going to use some off-brand cherry MX switches (probably outemu switches). Since mechanical keys simply allow current when pressed in, I do not need a resistor to protect the key switch.

So my question is “do I need a resistor for a keyboard key switch?”

Edit. 
So I am going to put it on a “keyboard matrix” that looks like the picture given (hopefully it was given. I don’t know how pictures work on the app)[image]

And each output from the matrix will go into the input on an arduino.

I think I got my answer, dim. The switch itself doesn’t need a resistor. But the Arduino might. Thanks all who had input. Much appreciated

Comment: Depends on where you are going to connect it...

Comment: You are building your own keyboard, but you don't know how to wire a switch? How do you plan on making the rest of the circuit!? The answer to your question is that it would depend on (the rest of the circuit)...Which you haven't explained to us.

Comment: Um... I’m still planning out the layout...but it will be in a “keyboard matrix”... I guess to answer your question, it will be between power and an input on a micro controller

Comment: "*Since mechanical keys simply allow current when pressed in...*" What do non-mechanical keys do?

Comment: Then think about how you *think* the circuit should be, then draw it here and ask about your doubts.

Comment: Easy, @Bort. OP, please can you edit your question and expand it considerably to explain your application. Make sure you add a schematic, the online schematic editor is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: Inputs on microcontrollers are almost certainly going to be high-impedance/resistance. If the received voltage is in-range, you won't need a resister. The switch itself should be able to handle the current without issue. I don't have much else to go on until you add more details.

Comment: “Since mechanical.....” in comparison to an LED that emits light with the current passing through.

Comment: Yes, you need pull-ups or pull-down resistors, depending on the polarity of the row (or col) select signal you'll be sending. These are not to protect the switch, but to force a "default" valid logic level on the arduino inputs. You could omit them if the Arduino can be configured with internal pull-ups/pull-downs (but I can't tell this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need resistors to protect the outputs of the keyboard controller, at least.

If you scan rows and read columns, then pressing two keys in the same column at the same time will connect two row outputs, while one is high and the other is low, leading to a short. So the bare minimum are current limiting resistors in the row lines, around 10k should be sufficient.

However, if you press two keys in the same column, the column line will then be driven to half the supply voltage, and you cannot get a clear reading then.

If you instead add one diode per key and a weak pulldown for each of the columns, you can build the matrix so that the column readback will capture the true state of each key, even if multiple keys are pressed at the same time. This is a bit more expensive, but definitely worth it if you ever want to use your keyboard for gaming.